# error running simple todo app code-AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to run the following code to generate a simple To Do list app using Angular: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kumarneetesh24/angular-app/master/mytodoapp.html

But I am getting the following output.

[image]

Could any one help me to find out what i am missing .Apart from this the app is not creating new tasks (upon entering and pressing go)

Comment: Add your Angular/HTML code

Comment: It seems angular.js or dependencies are not loaded porperly

Comment: it is better if you create any JSFiddle or add Code here.

Comment: And open your console, and read the error message. Post it if you don't understand it.

Comment: http://pastebin.ca/3385944

Comment: Your code, and the error message, must be **in the question itself**. Not as pastebin.

Comment: You Just got a copy paste of Code from some where asking for Help .. I see you have not done good amount research on it. i can close your question with appropriate tag .. Please update what you Understood before posting

Answer (score 1):

Your angular js file is not getting loaded .
use  this script tag :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

> You First Need to do some re-search and Understand the Concept . Looks
>   like you copy pasted the code from some where and asking for help .
>   This type of posts are not acceptable as per stack overflow documentation.
>
> Glad Some of the Guys helped you with out any suggestions which is
>   Good but at least let them know what they missing .

I provided you plunker :- 
       learn `todo`
    https://plnkr.co/edit/dA0bSLWm3T7KYctQosO7?p=preview

Understand your self and Update your post How you Figured
Thanks.
 .

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in your code. You must add localhost to the [Trusted Sites Zone](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/174360) or publish your code to the target server.